# selectonemenu, when editable=false, cannot submit the form

Tags: jsf, primefaces

My form is working if editable is set to true but not when it's false. When false the submit action method is not even called. I need it to be false (not editable so I can store the correct value in db).

This is the menu I added.

```
<tr><td>
<h:outputLabel for="country">#{registering.Country}: </h:outputLabel></td>
    <td><p:selectOneMenu editable="false" id="country" required="true" requiredMessage="Required" value="#{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}" converter="#{countriesConverter}" effect="fold" >
        <f:selectItem itemValue="#{null}" itemLabel="#{registering.SelectCountry}" />
        <f:selectItems value="#{countriesConverter.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.shortName}" itemValue="#{country}" />
    </p:selectOneMenu></td><td></td><td>
<span class="error"><h:message id="countryMessage" for="country"/></span></td>
</tr>
```

Notice that the select one menu has editable="false" it doesn't work in that case. But if I put editable="true" it works.

here is the full form,  last 2 fields are problematic:

```
<h:form>

   <table class="registration">             

        <!-- username -->
        <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="username">#{registering.Username}: </h:outputLabel></td><td>
        <p:inputText id="username" value="#{subscribeUser.user.username}" 
            validator="#{usernameValidator.validate}" maxlength="#{values.small}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="usernameCheck usernameMessage submit"></f:ajax>
        </p:inputText></td><td>
        <h:panelGroup id="usernameCheck">
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{usernameValidator.isIndicatorVisible.usernameFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{usernameValidator.isIndicatorVisible.usernameSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:panelGroup></td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="usernameMessage" for="username"/></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- password -->           

        <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="password">#{registering.Password}: </h:outputLabel></td><td>
        <p:password id="password" value="#{subscribeUser.userCredential.password}" feedback="true"

            promptLabel="#{registering.PleaseEnterPass}" weakLabel="#{registering.Weak}"
            goodLabel="#{registering.Good}" strongLabel="#{registering.Strong}"
            requiredMessage="#{registering.reqPassword}"
            validator="#{passwordValidator.validate}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:attribute name="confirm" value="#{confirmPassword}" />
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" execute="password confirmPassword" render="passwordMessage passwordCheck confpasswordCheck submit"></f:ajax>                       
        </p:password></td><td>
        <h:panelGroup id="passwordCheck">
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:panelGroup>
        </td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="passwordMessage" for="password"/></span></td>
        </tr>           

        <!-- Confirm password -->

        <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="confirmPassword" value="#{registering.ConfirmPass}: "/></td><td>
        <p:password id="confirmPassword" required="true"
            requiredMessage="#{registering.PleaseConfirmPassword}" 
            binding="#{confirmPassword}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" execute="password confirmPassword" render="passwordMessage passwordCheck confpasswordCheck submit"></f:ajax>

            </p:password> </td><td>
            <h:panelGroup id="confpasswordCheck">
                <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
                <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{passwordValidator.isIndicatorVisible.passwordSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
            </h:panelGroup>

            </td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="passwordConfMessage" for="confirmPassword" /></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Email -->

        <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="email">#{registering.Email}: </h:outputLabel></td><td>
        <p:inputText id="email" required="true" value="#{subscribeUser.user.email}" 
            validator="#{emailValidator.validate}"
            requiredMessage="#{registering.reqEmail}">
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="required" value="true"/>
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="type" value="email"/>
            <f:passThroughAttribute name="maxlength" value="100"/>
            <f:ajax event="blur" render="emailCheck emailMessage submit"></f:ajax>

        </p:inputText></td><td>
         <h:panelGroup id="emailCheck">
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="failed_indicator.png" rendered="#{emailValidator.isIndicatorVisible.emailFailed}"></h:graphicImage>
            <h:graphicImage library="images/icons" name="success_indicator.png" rendered="#{emailValidator.isIndicatorVisible.emailSuccess}"></h:graphicImage>
        </h:panelGroup> </td><td>
        <span class="error"><h:message id="emailMessage" for="email"/></span></td>
        </tr>

        <!-- Country -->

            <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="country">#{registering.Country}: </h:outputLabel></td>
        <td colspan="3"><p:selectOneMenu required="true" editable="true" id="country" value="#{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}" converter="#{countriesConverter}" effect="fold">
                <f:selectItems value="#{countriesConverter.countries}" var="country" itemLabel="#{country.shortName}" itemValue="#{country}" />
            </p:selectOneMenu></td>
        </tr>   
        <!-- Timezone -->   

         <tr><td>
        <h:outputLabel for="timezone">#{registering.Timezone}: </h:outputLabel></td>
        <td colspan="3">
            <p:selectOneMenu id="timezone" editable="true" required="true" value="#{subscribeUser.user.timezoneOffset}" converter="#{timezonesConverter}" effect="fold" >
                <f:selectItems value="#{timezonesConverter.timezonesList}" var="timezone" itemLabel="#{timezone.name}" itemValue="#{timezone}"  />

            </p:selectOneMenu></td>
        </tr>  



    </table>
    <div class="areYouARobot" ><div class="captchaLabel">#{registering.AreYouARobot}</div>
    <!-- <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6LdFTgcTAAAAAHQeLLEKPE-of2si0GrwuZXoEAHb"></div> --></div>
    <div class="submit">
    <p:commandButton value="#{registering.Submit}" id="submit" action="#{subscribeUser.inscrireUser}"  icon="ui-icon-disk" 
            disabled="#{!(usernameValidator.ok  and passwordValidator.ok and emailValidator.ok)}" >

    </p:commandButton></div>

</h:form>
```

Here is the country converter:

```
@ManagedBean
public class CountriesConverter implements Converter {
    private List<Country> countries;
    private List<String> countriesStr;
    private List<Integer> countriesId;
    private Country country;

    @EJB
    private CountriesService cs;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
        this.countries = cs.getAllCountries();
        this.countriesStr = new ArrayList<String>();
        this.countriesId = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        for (Country c : countries) {
            this.countriesStr.add(c.getShortName());
        }
        for (Country c : countries) {
            this.countriesId.add(c.getIdCountry());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Country getAsObject(FacesContext ctx, UIComponent component,
            String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }

        try {
            return cs.findByName(submittedValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext fc, UIComponent uic,
            Object modelValue) {

        Country datCountry = (Country) modelValue;
        if (datCountry == null) {
            return "";
        }

        else if (datCountry instanceof Country) {
            return datCountry.getShortName();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
    //get&sets
}
```

The country entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="countries")
@NamedQuery(name="Country.findAll", query="SELECT c FROM Country c")
public class Country implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private int idCountry;

    @Column(name="calling_code")
    private String callingCode;

    private String cctld;

    private String iso2;

    private String iso3;

    @Column(name="long_name")
    private String longName;

    private String numcode;

    @Column(name="short_name")
    private String shortName;

    @Column(name="un_member")
    private String unMember;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to User
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="countryBean")
    private List<User> users;

    public Country() {
    }
    //getter & setters
}
```

My timezone converter:

```
@ManagedBean
public class TimezonesConverter implements Converter {

    private List<Timezone> timezonesList;
    private Map<String, Timezone> myMap;
    private static final String[] timezonesStr = {
            "(GMT -12:00) Eniwetok, Kwajalein",
            "etcetera" };

    public TimezonesConverter() {
        timezonesList = new ArrayList<Timezone>();
        myMap = new TreeMap<String, Timezone>();
        int offset = -720;
        for (String s : timezonesStr) {
            Timezone timezone = new Timezone(s, offset);
            timezonesList.add(timezone);
            myMap.put(s, timezone);
            offset += 60;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1,
            String submittedValue) {
        if (submittedValue == null || submittedValue.isEmpty()) {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return myMap.get(submittedValue);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1,
            Object modelValue) {
        // casting error here.
        Timezone timezone = (Timezone) modelValue;
        if (timezone == null) {
            return "";
        } else if (timezone instanceof Timezone) {
            return timezone.getName();
        } else {
            return null;
        }
    }
//getters
}
```

Timezone class:

```
public class Timezone {
    private String name;
    private int offset;

    public Timezone(String name, int offset) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = offset;
    }
//getters and setters
}
```

I commented the timezone thing but when uncommented it gives me this error, which makes no sens to me since the var I put in the timezone menu is a timezone object:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Integer cannot be cast to main.java.utils.Timezone
    at main.java.converters.TimezonesConverter.getAsString(TimezonesConverter.java:82)
```

I did a workaround for this but I'm unhappy with it:

```
@Override
public String getAsString(FacesContext arg0, UIComponent arg1,
        Object modelValue) {
    int offset = (int) modelValue;
    if (modelValue == null) {
        return "";
    } else {
        for (Timezone tz : timezonesList) {
            if (tz.getOffset() == offset) {
                return tz.getName();
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

and I switched the value in the form to :

```
<f:selectItems value="#{timezonesConverter.timezonesList}" var="timezone" itemLabel="#{timezone.name}" itemValue="#{timezone.offset}"  />
```

So instead of the value being a Timezone object (that x reason was considered as an Integer and caused the cast exception), it is the int variable inside the Timezone object that is taken, and that works.

the user entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQuery(name="User.findAll", query="SELECT u FROM User u")
public class User implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    private String username;

    private String email;

    @Column(name="is_enabled")
    private int isEnabled;

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="member_since")
    private Date memberSince;

    @Column(name="profile_pic")
    private String profilePic;

    private int reputation;

    private String role;

    private String status;

    private int timezoneOffset;

    @Column(name="warning_lvl")
    private int warningLvl;

    private String xxx;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Friend
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user1")
    private List<Friend> friends1;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Friend
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user2")
    private List<Friend> friends2;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Message
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user1")
    private List<Message> messages1;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Message
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user2")
    private List<Message> messages2;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Thethread
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user1")
    private List<Thethread> thethreads1;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Thethread
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user2")
    private List<Thethread> thethreads2;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Usercfg
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Usercfg> usercfgs;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Userinfo
    @OneToMany(mappedBy="user")
    private List<Userinfo> userinfos;

    //bi-directional many-to-one association to Country
    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="country")
    private Country countryBean;

    public User() {
    }
    // getters & setters
}
```

Comment: That exception doesn't make any sense given the code you have posted. What is the exact line number of the exception?

Comment: I add the full stack trace because there is none in my opinion

Comment: I can't think of a good reason for your validator to be `@ViewScoped` and `@ManagedBean`. I would remove those annotations. I've never seen them used in any `@FacesValidator` examples. I don't know if they're causing the issue, but they can't be helping.

Comment: As for the stacktrace, it sort of looks like the framework is trying to inject a String into that field. That doesn't make any sense, but it's what it looks like to me.

Comment: I deleted the two lines you suggested but I'm getting an error that EmailValidator is null. I made the form some weeks ago and I'm 50% sure I had to use it as viewscoped for a reason I don't know yet. I'll look that up. I'm adding the full form to the post aswell.

Comment: Ok so I've more multiple fields tested by multiple validators. In each validator I've a variable which says it the test passed. My submit button is disabled unless those tests passed. That's why they are viewscoped. Anyway, the thing is this is a form that was working yesterday. I just added the country and timezones field (I omited timezone field in my original post).

Comment: If it was working yesterday and you don't have a better idea, back-out the changes and confirm it's working. Then re-introduce the changes one by one. Unless you have a better idea, of course.

Comment: I pinpointed the reason. The reason is that editable is set to false, when true it's working. That's weird.

Comment: What is the type of #{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}? Could you please also post the bean code and the converter code?

Comment: @user423948123 done. I also added the full form that contains another selectOneMenu timezone which gives me a cast exception.

Comment: Noticed you miss the equals and hashCode methods on the Country and Timezone. Timezone is also not Serializable. And I expect the problem in #{subscribeUser.user.countryBean}, could you add also the User entity code?

Comment: Added. I found a workaround to the casting problem. It's illogical to me why I'd have to do it though.

Comment: @user423948123 but concerning your last comment. When in my SelectOneMenu the items are the objects in a List. Why would these objects be considered as Integer ? I'm falling short on that one.

Comment: Because you have it defined on the User entity, check your code and my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason why method is not called is, that conversion of values fails.

### Country field

CountriesConverter method getAsObject should have return type Object, I expect it's not called at all now.

Country class must implement the equals and hashCode methods.

### Timezone field

The timezoneOffset property of the User class must be instance of the Timezone class.

OR

Keep the timezoneOffset int, remove the converter and set the int value using the itemValue attribute. See the example:

```
<p:selectOneMenu id="timezone" editable="true" required="true" 
        value="#{subscribeUser.user.timezoneOffset}" effect="fold" >
    <f:selectItems value="#{timezonesConverter.timezonesList}" var="timezone" 
        itemLabel="#{timezone.name}" itemValue="#{timezone.offset}"  />
</p:selectOneMenu>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! The error in the timezone field was indeed due to the fact that my User bean timezone field was an int and not a timezone object. before doing that field I thought I had to do the conversion but somehow I lost track. That resolved the timezone field so thanks a lot for that. As for the country field, the getAsObject is called, I persist in the database. **Unless** editable is set to false. I'm not sure why you think equals and hashcode methods might resolve the issue. I'm gonna give it a try though.

Comment: Entities always MUST implement equals and hashCode, because they must be compared by IDs. User with id 1 is user with id 1, no matter how the object was initialized.

Comment: Waw, it works. I would never have found this by myself. Even worse when trying I was thinking "this is never gonna work" and tried out of last hope lol. But what has the field editable to do with this ? Thanks a lot dude. If I could give you my karma points I would.

Comment: Thanks, it was easy to help you when you provided the code. If the editable attribute is set to true, PrimeFaces treats the value attribute to handle String. When editable is set to false, it works as a <h:selectOneListbox size="1"...>, then the converter comes into play and object equality also. I expect the value passed to the setCountry to be null with editable attribute true - the setCountry should then expect String, then it would work...